# Expo update App to Play Store - wrong key

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-console, expo

I published a first version of my application to the Play Store successfully.

I've made some few hot fix in my JS and I want to publish the update on the Play Store.

So I've run the command :

```
expo build:android -t app-bundle
```

To create a new version of my application

Then I've upload the .aab file to the Play Console. And here is the message :

```
Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again
```

I don't know exactly what I did wrong

Comment: You have to signed this update app bundle with key used while signing first version of app abb

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I shouldn't let expo handle the keystore for me ?

Comment: I haven't used expo, but possibly you might not be building a release bundle but instead a debug version of the app. I have found this tutorial how to sign a app bundle with expo: https://medium.com/@danigonlinea/how-to-sign-your-expo-app-by-google-play-successfully-b591471538cb

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reset the Keystore for Google Play, then you can contact Google Play Console support and they can reset it for you.

In the play console click the help button at the top > Scroll down to heed more help and click "Contact Us" > Type in you need help with a Keystore Reset > Click "next step" > Click "Upload key reset request" > Click "Contact Google Play Developer Support" > Then choose a contact method to contact them to reset it for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, that's exactly what I did.

But everytime I will update my app, I'll get to reset de Keystore ? (I believe that the answer is no)